# MS Word AddIn / VSTO manually hard disable

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, add-in

is there any way to (hard)disable a MS Word add-in/VSTO? I found lots of information for troubleshooting and re-enabling add-ins, but nothing about how to hard-disable a Word Add-In/VSTO. I need to create a testscenario for my client and it would be nice if someone have any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution...-> https://ardamis.com/2010/02/26/fixing-word-2007-add-in-issues/

> Forcing add-ins to be disabled by Word
>
> To test, you may be able to cause add-ins to be disabled by forcibly
>   ending the winword.exe process while Word is loading, or after it has
>   invoked a function from the add-in. It might require crashing Word a
>   few times, but eventually you’ll get an error:
>
> Microsoft Office Word Word experienced a serious problem with the
>   ‘[add-in name]’ add-in. If you have seen this message multiple times,
>   you should disable this add-in and check to see if an update is
>   available. Do you want to disable this add-in? [Yes] [No]
>
> If you click Yes, the add-in will be hard-disabled and an entry will
>   be created in
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Resiliency\DisabledItems